# How make setParseAction work when chain several definitions (like FLOAT derive from INT) building AST

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree, pyparsing

I'm struggling to make work `setParseAction` when inherit definitions (I don't know how express this in english, so the example):

```
from __future__ import division
from decimal import Decimal

from pyparsing import Word, alphas, ParseException, Literal, CaselessLiteral \
        , Combine, Optional, nums, Or, Forward, ZeroOrMore, StringEnd, alphanums, Suppress \
        , sglQuotedString, dblQuotedString, Group \
        , restOfLine, Regex, stringEnd


class ASTNode(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens
        self.assignFields()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + ':' + str(self.__dict__)
    __repr__ = __str__


class ConstantNode(ASTNode):
    def assignFields(self):
        #print "  ", self.tokens
        self.setValue(self.tokens[0])

    def transform(self, value):
        return value

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.constant = self.transform(value)
        del self.tokens


class StringNode(ConstantNode):
    pass


class BoolNode(ConstantNode):
    def transform(self, value):
        return bool(value)


class IntNode(ConstantNode):
    def transform(self, value):
        return int(value)


class FloatNode(ConstantNode):
    def transform(self, value):
        print value
        return Decimal(value)


class AssignmentNode(ASTNode):
    def assignFields(self):
        #print self.tokens
        self.lhs, self.rhs = self.tokens
        del self.tokens


LPAR, RPAR, LBRACK, RBRACK, LBRACE, RBRACE, SEMI, COMMA = map(Suppress, "()[]{};,")

PLUS = Literal("+")
MINUS = Literal("-")
MULT = Literal("*")
DIV = Literal("/")

ASSIGN = Literal("=")
POINT = Literal('.')

TRUE = Literal('True')
FALSE = Literal('False')

SEP = Literal(':').suppress()

NAME = Word(alphas + '_?', alphanums + '_?')
TYPE = SEP + NAME
COMMENT = "#" + restOfLine

BOOLEANS = TRUE | FALSE
BOOLEANS.setParseAction(BoolNode)

EXPR = Forward()

ADDOP = PLUS | MINUS
MULTOP = MULT | DIV
PLUSORMINUS = PLUS | MINUS

#Strings
STR = dblQuotedString.setParseAction(ConstantNode) | sglQuotedString.setParseAction(ConstantNode)

STRINGS = STR

#Numbers
NUMBER = Word(nums)
INTEGER = Combine(Optional(PLUSORMINUS) + NUMBER)
FLOATNUMBER = Combine(INTEGER.copy() +
                       Optional(POINT + Optional(NUMBER)) +
                       Optional(INTEGER.copy())
                )

MONEY = Combine(FLOATNUMBER.copy() + Word("$").suppress())
TYPED_FLOATNUMBER = Combine(FLOATNUMBER + Word(alphas))

INTEGER.setParseAction(IntNode)
FLOATNUMBER.setParseAction(FloatNode)

NUMBERS = MONEY | TYPED_FLOATNUMBER | FLOATNUMBER


TEST_GRAMMAR = """
#Single values
True
False
1 #Int32
1.0 #Float
1$ #MONEY
25.3mt #Typed number"""
```

Everything parse, but the Boolean and Int node are not called, only the float.

```
['True']
['False']
1
[FloatNode:{'constant': Decimal('1')}]
1.0
[FloatNode:{'constant': Decimal('1.0')}]
['1']
['25.3mt']
[ConstantNode:{'constant': "'hello world'"}]
[ConstantNode:{'constant': '"hello world"'}]
['2002-08-10']
['100000']
['2002-08-10-100000']
1
[AssignmentNode:{'rhs': FloatNode:{'constant': Decimal('1')}, 'lhs': 'x'}]
1.0
[AssignmentNode:{'rhs': FloatNode:{'constant': Decimal('1.0')}, 'lhs': 'x'}]
[AssignmentNode:{'rhs': '1', 'lhs': 'x'}]
[AssignmentNode:{'rhs': '12.2mt', 'lhs': 'x'}]
```

I understand that setParseAction is tied to the definition of a partial grammar. However, I find it don't "clear" if chain something like `FLOATNUMBER` because is based on `INTEGER`.

Comment: In the code you posted, you define FLOATNUMBER using INTEGER.copy(), and you don't set the parse action on INTEGER until after this is done - so there is no collision of parse actions between the two.

Comment: Yep, that is something I figure at last moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out the code that does the actual parsing, so I added this code:

```
for line in TEST_GRAMMAR.splitlines():
    if not line or line[0] == '#': continue
    print (BOOLEANS^INTEGER^NUMBERS).parseString(line)
```

Giving this output:

```
[BoolNode:{'constant': True}]
[BoolNode:{'constant': False}]
[IntNode:{'constant': 1}]
1.0
[FloatNode:{'constant': Decimal('1.0')}]
['1']
['25.3mt']
```

I also had to fix a minor bug in BoolNode:

```
class BoolNode(ConstantNode):
    def transform(self, value):
        return value.lower()=='true' #bool(value)
```

In `transform`, value is going to be one of the strings "True" or "False", but the `bool` value of both of these strings is True - only the empty string "" will return a bool of False.

One of the problems you have is that your definition of FLOAT will also match an INTEGER, so you might consider redefining FLOAT to require a leading, trailing, or embedded decimal point. I got around this by using '^' instead of '|' as the "or" operator. '^' will test *all* the given alternatives and select the *longest* match, '|' will short-circuit and select the *first* match.

Comment: This lead me to the right path. I have not understand the meaning of "|" and don't know about "^". Thanks

Comment: '|' operator is used as in `expr_a | expr_b | expr_c` - '|' operator creates a pyparsing MatchFirst, which will test expr_a, and if no match expr_b, then if still no match expr_c.  The '^' operator as in `expr_a ^ expr_b ^ expr_c` - creates a pyparsing Or. Or will test all three expressions, and then select the one that matches the longest text.